# How to get range of records from TEMP TABLE with alphanumeric column?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I have a TEMP TABLE with an alphanumeric column and I want to get the range of records on basis of 2 filters.

```
**Filters:** Begin filter and End filter.

**For Example: Column data:**
A123
A145
B002
B234
C095
C456
D001
D345
```

Begin filter -> A14 and End filter -> D12

```
**Expected Result:**
A145
B002
B234
C095
C456
D001
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
FOR EACH ttName 
   WHERE ttName.FieldName >= "A14" and ttName.FieldName <= "D12"
   NO-LOCK:

        /* do stuff */

END.
```

Comment: It will work, but I want something like between in sql. If there is no record with D12, then it should automatically pick previous one.

Comment: Progress is NOT SQL.  The more you try to make it be like SQL the unhappier you will be.

Comment: @Tom is there any way to get the between functionality in progress??

Comment: No.  Progress is not SQL.  You cannot successfully use SQL syntax within a 4gl program.  The correct way to do this is as Tim has shown.

Comment: @Tom I already did that way, but requirement is different. Okay thank for your time guys 

Comment: Perhaps you should state the "requirement"?  From your original question it certainly looks like the requirement has been met.  If the code must somehow say "between" somewhere try embedding a comment.

Comment: @TomBascom Apologies for late reply
Requirement:
1) No End Range Record exists, return Display Range between the Begin Record and the assumed End Record.

2) No Begin Range Record exists, return Display Range between the assumed Begin Record and the last End Record.

3) No Begin Range and no End Range Record, return Display Range between the assumed Begin Record and the last End Record.

Thanks

Comment: @TomBascom
Requirement is in SQL query mention below:

SELECT * FROM test.temp where tempcol between 'A14' and  'D12'

If we can get the result in Progress as above query getting in SQL, my requirement will be fulfilled.

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like Tim's solution meets your requirement perfectly.

Comment: @TomBascom As mentioned in my question, there is no 'D12' records in the grid. So according to Tim's solution it will show all the record 
ttName.FieldName >= 'A14'.

It means D345 also will be display in the grid.

What do you think?

Comment: I think that you are probably misunderstanding how AND works and that you might want to try actually running Tim's code.